# How to get a list of ALL block hashes yet?

Tags: blockchain, mining, blocks, hash, export

I'm looking for a way/link/service to get a list of ALL (~4400000) block hashes yet.

Any idea how to get that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickBlocks provides a command line tool [`getBlock`](https://github.com/Great-Hill-Corporation/quickBlocks/blob/master/src/tools/getBlock/README.md) that can do this. It runs against a local node, if present, or Infura if not. It retrieves only 10,000 blocks at a time, but you could write a shell script to loop over (with a sleep to allow for Infura's rate limit). You call it with

```
getBlock start-stop
```

and it prints all JSON for all the blocks from `start` to `stop`. You could do

```
getBlock start-stop | grep hash
```

to retieve only the hashes.

[**Full disclosure:** I wrote QuickBlocks. Sorry to keep shilling  it, but it actually does answer this question directly. We're announcing parts of it as open source very soon.]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a service that just provides exactly that.

You can use Etherscan o Infura nodes to query all blocks, and store the hashes in a database. But those services have rate limits and very like you will reach them when querying for that amount of blocks.

You can setup your own node. If you need block hashes it is very likely you might need in the future transactions data. So having a node my provide more flexible queries going forward.

Also you can put a bounty in reddit.com/r/ethereum if someones provides the data.